# Write values with embedded commas from arrays into CSV file using BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, csv, array

I am trying to write different arrays into a csv file ($file) columns.
Each array has the same number of values.
For example, arr1 and arr2 have 3 values each

```
arr1=( 23 45 34 )
arr2=( "abc,d"  ef  g )
```

I tried the following code but I'm getting the wrong results

```
for i in "${!arr1[@]}"; do
echo  "${arr1[i]}, ${arr2[i]}"  >> $file
done
```

I'm getting the following where col1, col2 and col3 are 3 columns.

```
col1    col2    col3
23      "abc    d"
45       ef 
34       g
```

but the desired result is

```
col1    col2   
23      "abc,d"
45       ef 
34       g
```

It seems like the embedded coma in "abc,d" creates a problem.
Anyone knows a way around this or any better way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that $file needs to be defined...

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question exactly how you are looking at the file (perhaps with a spreadsheet program?) however the shell is likely stripping off the quotes in your array definition: if you want embedded commas to be handled in a CSV-complient way, you should add them as literal quotes ex.

```
arr1=( 23 45 34 )
arr2=( \"abc,d\"  ef  g )
```

so that the shell's internal representation looks like

```
$ declare -p arr1 arr2
declare -a arr1=([0]="23" [1]="45" [2]="34")
declare -a arr2=([0]="\"abc,d\"" [1]="ef" [2]="g")
```

Then for example

```
for i in "${!arr1[@]}"; do 
  printf '%s,%s\n' "${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[i]}"
done > "$file"
```

results in

```
$ cat "$file"
23,"abc,d"
45,ef
34,g
```

Another option is to quote all fields ex.

```
arr1=( 23 45 34 )
arr2=( "abc,d"  ef  g )

for i in "${!arr1[@]}"; do 
  printf '"%s","%s"\n' "${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[i]}"
done > "$file"
```

giving

```
$ cat "$file"
"23","abc,d"
"45","ef"
"34","g"
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that your data contains no literal tabs.

Start by creating a simple column for each array (with header), and combine them using `paste`, creating a TSV data stream:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

arr1=( 23 45 34 )
arr2=( abc,d ef g )

paste <( echo col1; printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}" ) \
      <( echo col2; printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}" )
```

The output of this will read

```
col1    col2
23      abc,d
45      ef
34      g
```

You can then use Miller to convert it into properly quoted CSV:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

arr1=( 23 45 34 )
arr2=( abc,d ef g )

paste <( echo col1; printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}" ) \
      <( echo col2; printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}" ) | mlr --t2c cat
```

This would generate

```
col1,col2
23,"abc,d"
45,ef
34,g
```

... which a CSV-aware program would read as

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | abc,d |
| 45 | ef |
| 34 | g |

A CSV-aware spreadsheet program would likely also be able to read that TSV data, so Miller would not be strictly needed.